# android:onClick="onGroupItemClick" keeps crashing

Tags: android, menu

Here is some code which keeps crashing (a simplified version from a book). Android version 14.
If I remove the line: android:onClick="onGroupItemClick", it will be ok.
Does anybody know why and how to fix it.

Thanks

```
activity_menu_test.xml:
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu1"
        android:title="Item 1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu2"
        android:title="Item 2">
        <menu>
            <group
                android:id="@+id/group1"
                android:checkableBehavior="single" >
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/group_item1"
                    android:onClick="onGroupItemClick"
                    android:title="Sub1"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/group_item2"
                    android:onClick="onGroupItemClick"
                    android:title="Sub2"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/group_item3"
                    android:onClick="onGroupItemClick"
                    android:title="Sub3"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>


MenuTestActivity:
public class MenuTestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_test);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_menu_test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onGroupItemClick(MenuItem item) {   
        if (item.isChecked()) {
            item.setChecked(false); 
        } else {
            item.setChecked(true);
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {    
        Toast.makeText(this, item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;    
    }    
}
```

java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing line: null
    at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:313)
    at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:247)
    at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.getNetworkStatsDetailGroupedByUid(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5734)
    at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.access$100(BatteryStatsImpl.java:76)
    at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid.computeCurrentTcpBytesReceived(BatteryStatsImpl.java:2457)
    at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid.getTcpBytesReceived(BatteryStatsImpl.java:2446)
    at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeSummaryToParcel(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5437)
    at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:4836)
    at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeAsyncLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:4818)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateCpuStatsNow(ActivityManagerService.java:1600)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$3.run(ActivityManagerService.java:1482)
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:78)
    at java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:42)
    at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:272)
    ... 10 more
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:98)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
    ... 13 more

Comment: what do you understand by *crashes*? post your LogCat output.